# Para que serve o operador "super()" no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, construtor, super

Qual a funcionalidade do operador `super()` que fica dentro do método `constructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele não é um operador, é uma forma de chamar um construtor de forma específica, então é uma construção da linguagem através de uma palavra chave.

Ele serve justamente para chamar o construtor da classe herdada ali. "Sempre" que faz um construtor em uma classe derivada você deve querer fazer uma construção específica dela, mas para o objeto ficar completo deve fazer a parte da construção da classe base (a mãe). Então essa é a forma de fazer isso.

Na verdade essa palavra é usada para acessar todo o objeto base, portanto pode usar para chamar método e propriedades dele, o construtor é só um deles.

Conhece o `this`, certo? Que é o que usa para acessar o objeto atual. Ele é o `this` do objeto base e não o atual.

No construtor ele deve ser usado antes de qualquer `this`, portanto deve começar construir primeiro o objeto base para depois mexer no objeto atual que está construindo.

Para ficar mais claro não é que haverá dois objetos, haverá apenas um, mas será um objeto que tem duas partes lógicas, uma que foi definida na classe base e outra que está definida na classe atual. Não existe fisicamente duas coisas separadas, é só para entender melhor a questão da herança.

Isto dá erro porque não está construindo a parte do objeto base:

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(height, width) {
        this.name = 'Rectangle';
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
    sayName() {
        console.log('Hi, I am a ', this.name + '.');
    }
    get area() {
        return this.height * this.width;
    }
    set area(value) {
        this._area = value;
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
    constructor(length) {
//        super(length, length);
        this.height;
        this.name = 'Square';
    }
}

console.log(new Square(10));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Super.js).

Esse `super()` é como se estivesse chamando `new Rectangule(length, length);`, mas por que não chama assim? Justamente porque você não qier criar um outro objeto, o objeto está sendo criado ali mesmo, mas você quer que parte dele que foi herdado seja inicializado ali no construtor atual.
Por que não chama sozinho? Porque pode ter outros construtores e a forma de chamar pode não ser tão simples assim. Só consegue fazer isso se for um construtor padrão.

Entenda [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Tem uma série de regras para seguir conforme pode ser visto na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).